# probability generating function for multivariate distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, generating-functions

I would like to ask **how can we derive PGF of any multivariate distribution**?
and can anyone give **an example** of deriving the PGF of a multivariate distribution?
That will be great.
Thanks advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have in general $$G(\mathbf{z}) = G(z_1,\ldots,z_d)=\operatorname{E}\bigl (z_1^{X_1}\cdots z_d^{X_d}\bigr) = \sum_{x_1,\ldots,x_d=0}^{\infty}p(x_1,\ldots,x_d)z_1^{x_1}\cdots z_d^{x_d}$$

So suppose for example $$P(\mathbf{X}=(0,0))=\frac45, \,P(\mathbf{X}=(1,0))=\frac35, \,P(\mathbf{X}=(0,1))=\frac25, \, P(\mathbf{X}=(1,1))=\frac15,$$ then rather simply you have  $$G(\mathbf{z})=\frac45 + \frac35 z_1 + \frac25 z_2 + \frac15 z_1z_2.$$

Sometimes a particular multivariate distribution will allow some simplification.  In particular, if the components $X_1,X_2,\ldots, X_d$ of $\mathbf{X}$ are independently distributed then you have $$G(\mathbf{z}) = G_1(z_1)G_2(z_2)\cdots G_d(z_d).$$

Comment: That was clear if we know the probabilities. However, If we have probability function of any multivariate distribution {Poisson, binomial, ...}, Is there any example how to derive the PGF of them ?

Comment: @LeanBader: Are the components of your multivariate Poisson/binomial/... distribution independent? If not, then what is the distribution?

Comment: My distribution is multivariate Poisson distribution and I want to understand how can I derive the PGF for another multivariate distribution to know the steps and try to find the PGF of my distribution.

Comment: I derived the formula of pmf of MP distribution and I'm trying to derive its PGF.

Comment: So what is the probability mass function?

Comment: I suppose that is supposed to be something like $\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{\min(x_1,...,x_n)}\frac{\theta_{0}^{i‌​}\exp(-\theta_{0})}{i!} \prod_{j=1}^n \frac {θ_j^{x_j−i} \exp(-\theta _j)}{(x_j−i)!}$  although I am not inclined to do the calculations

Comment: Yes, this is the pmf